# MPU-6050 not working

Tags: arduino, i2c, mpu6050

I am trying to make an accelerometer based mouse. I am using a MPU-6050 for my accelerometer. I have connected the ports the following:

- VCC - 5V
- GND - GND
- SCL - A4
- SDA - A5
- INT - 2

Here is my code:

```cpp
// MPU-6050 Short Example Sketch
// By Arduino User JohnChi
// August 17, 2014
// Public Domain
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;
String movement = " ";
String movementup = " ";
void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){

  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)     
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)



  if(AcX < -4000 && AcY < 4000 && AcY > -4000 ){
    Serial.println("8");//D
  }else{
    Serial.println("");
  }
  if(AcX > 4000 && AcY < 4000 && AcY > -4000 ){
    Serial.println("7");//A
  }else{
    Serial.println( "");
  }
  if(AcY < -3000 && AcX < 3000 && AcX > -3000 ){
    Serial.println("6");//W
  }else{
    Serial.println("");
  }
  if(AcY >4000 && AcX < 4000 && AcX > -4000 ){
    Serial.println("5");//S
  }else{
    Serial.println("");
  }
  if(AcY > 4000 && AcX > 4000){
    Serial.println("4");//SA
  }else{
    Serial.println("");
  }
  if(AcY < -4000 && AcX < -4000){
    Serial.println("3");//WD
  }else{
    Serial.println("");
  }
   if(AcY < -4000 && AcX > 4000){
    Serial.println("2");//WA
  }else{
    Serial.println("");
  }
  if(AcY > 4000 && AcX < -4000){
    Serial.println("1");//sd
  }else{
    Serial.println("");
  }

  // Serial.print(movement);
 //Serial.println("|| AcX ="),Serial.print (AcX);
 //Serial.println("|| AcY ="),Serial.print (AcY);


 // Serial.print(movementup);


  delay(333);


  }
```

But whenever I try and run the program the output goes like this:

```
AcX AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.53 | GyX = -1 | GyY = -1 | GyZ = -1
AcX = -1 | AcY = -1 | AcZ = -1 | Tmp = 36.
```

I have tried to use the I2C checker it gave me this:

```
I2C Scanner
Scanning...
No I2C devices found
```

If anyone has any answers please comment!

Comment: Which Arduino are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an Arduino Uno you have swapped SDA and SCL wires.

According to this site:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire

> Board I2C / TWI pins
>
> Uno, Ethernet    **A4 (SDA), A5 (SCL)**
>
> Mega2560         20 (SDA), 21 (SCL)
>
> Leonardo  2 (SDA), 3 (SCL)
>
> Due   20 (SDA), 21 (SCL),
> SDA1, SCL1

Make sure you use the right pins

Comment: Piglet, Thank you this. You helped me solve a problem that almost drove me insane.